# Stream video from one client to another client through a server

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, node.js, websocket

I am trying to send a video stream from one laptop to another laptop, and route it through a server. Lets call them laptop A sending a video stream to laptop B.

On laptop A, I have no particular requirement to how I collect the video stream, but I was thinking there would be some sort of NodeJS server running that opens a web socket to a server to send back the video stream.

On laptop B, I'd like to render the video inside of a browser in a html5 video tag.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done technically?

The gaps I don't really understand are:
* How to send a stream from laptop A to a server (which could also be running NodeJS)
* How to provide a video stream that can be plugged into a video tag on laptop B

Thanks!

Comment: WebRTC:  https://webrtc.org/

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this with javscript/html5 is really to choose the wrong technology. You should have a look on Flash (and RTMP) on the client side, and use any of the free (open source) Flash Media Server alternatives out there. (You must have a plugin like Flash or Silverlight to get access to the webcam data - your web browser/javascript can not access the webcam.)

node-rtmp is a RTMP protocol server written in Node.JS, that might be in your interest. I have not tested node-rtmp myself, but it can be a starting point for you. If it does not suite you, there are multiple other RTMP server projects out there. (I have used Red5 a lot, which is in java.)

On Computer A you would then need a Flash application that takes your webcam data and sends it to the RTMP server. There are open source projects doing this already, for example:
https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming
There is also example code of such flash applications included in Red5, and possibly also in other RTMP server projects.

You can not use the HTML video tag to display a RTMP stream on Computer B. If it is RTMP, then you will have to use a Flash player. It might be possible to convert the RTMP data to something else, to make it possible to show with a HTML video tag. It would (probably) be possible to do with a combination of Open Source Softwares like Red5, rtmpdump, ffmpeg and some http hacking to make it go over http. However, I would really consider if it is worth the work and hassle to do that just for not running a Flash application...

On Computer B, I would use jwplayer (or any of the jwplayer clones) to play the RTMP stream.

Comment: I'm very open to ideas, I'd just like Laptop B to be rendering into a video tag. It sounds like you are suggesting setting up an RTMP server on the server side... but I don't' know enough on how the rest should work. Can you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Added some more info on this.